# Using data structure methods in main class c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access methods in my Element structure in my main method. I keep getting an error stating that

> "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "Element::Element()", referenced from:
>
> _main in Element.o
>
> _main in main.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)"

Element header

```
#ifndef Element_hpp
#define Element_hpp

struct Element {
public:
    int getNumber(void);
    void setNumber(int n);
    int getSteps();
    void setSteps();
    Element();
private:
    int number;
    int stepN;
};

#endif /* Element_hpp */
```

Element class

```
#include "Element.hpp"
#include "main.cpp"

int Element::getNumber() {
    return number;
}

void Element::setNumber(int n) {
    number = n;
    setSteps();
}

int Element::getSteps() {
    return stepN;
}

int steps(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = n;
    while(j != 1) {
        if(j % 2 == 1) {
            j = (3 * j + 1) / 2;
            i = i + 2;
        }
        else if(j % 2 == 0) {
            j= j / 2;
            i= i + 1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

void Element::setSteps() {
    stepN = steps(number);
}
```

Main class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <String>
#include <fstream>
#include "Element.hpp"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::ofstream data;
    data.open("data.txt");
    int end = 1000;
    Element* e = new Element[end];
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        e[i].setNumber(i);
        e[i].setSteps();
    }
    heapSort(e, end);
    printArray(e, end);
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is too obvious. You declared but failed to define the class's constructor. What exactly do you not understand here?

Comment: How do you compile and link your code? Are you using the command line or an IDE? Are you using any build told such as make?

Answer (score 1):

You should never #include CPP files. Instead you should link them. The most straight forward way is from the command line:

```
$ g++ main.cpp element.cpp
```

I suggest that you read about the C++ build process including the difference between compiling and linking.

Comment: Although true, this does not answer the question, and has nothing to do with the link failure.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I saw the declaration but missed that there is no matching definition.

Answer (score 1):

As [Sam Varshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) mentioned in the comment, you declared

```
Element::Element()
```

on your Element header file but did not define it. Adding

```
Element::Element() {
}
```

to your Element class file should allow the linker to find the missing symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `Element();` constructor in Element header file but you have not defined it in any file.

You may want to add this in your Element implementation file:

```
Element::Element() {
}
```